# How to acces an item from a TreeMap using an int index?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap defined like this private `TreeMap <String,Enclavament> a_enclavaments;`. I want to work with every Enclavament of the TreeMap, so I made a for look to run a method on them, this is what I mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a_enclavaments.size(); i++)
    modify(a_enclavaments.get(i));
```

modify requires an items from the class Enclavament.
However, when I start, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
```

I don't understand why. I've read the java APIs and it says

```
get(Object key)
     Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or if this map contains no mapping for the key.
```

Isn't it supposed to return the first, then second, then third... Enclavament from the TreeMap?
EDIT: Can it be because I have the first, let's say, parameter on the TreeMap set as a String and it has to be an Integer?

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: Look at the `modify()` method that accepts Integer not String

Comment: `TreeMap` is key-value pair.

Comment: your key is string and you are passing an int...a treemap is not an ordered collection so you don't need indexes to access values in it.

Comment: The question is - why is your data in a `TreeMap` and keyed by a `String`, if you want then to iterate over it? Why a `TreeMap` and why those particular keys? If you can anser this properly, you'll either get to a different data structure (a sorted `List`?) or use a different key (e.g. `Integer` if your keys are sparse), or would use a simple for-each loop to iterate over the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s store a value based on a key. The key serves to define the location of the value inside the `Map` data structure (array, linked list, tree, etc. depending on the implementation of the `Map`). By knowing this, a `Map` doesn't work with `index` concept, only key.

In this case, you're setting a `String` value as your key, but trying to retrieve the data using an `Integer`, and the exception is pretty clear about it:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

One possible solution may be to change the key to `Integer` instead (if possible).

If you want/need to iterate over the values on the `Map`, you may use a `for` loop on [`Map#values`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--):

```
for (Enclavament enclavement : a_enclavaments.values) {
    //do what you want/need
}
```

If using the latter, there's no need to change the type of the key of your `Map`.

Comment: The guy simply wants to iterate over the values. That's a simple task to do, isn't it? That, or he might be using a wrong collection for what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought... So it looks like I have to either change the key to an Integer or use the get() method with a String?

Comment: @p.bosch it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @p.bosch +1 or you can use a for-each loop which appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to access an entry that doesn't exist according to the key type of your map (that is, you're attempting to find a `String` key when passing in an `Integer`.

Internally, the map is attempting to cast what you passed in as the key you're searching on to match the key the map is defined to accept.  A `String` can't cast to an `Integer`, hence your exception.

It seems like you just want to iterate over the contents of your map.  That can be accomplished with an [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29):

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Enclavement> entry : a_enclavement.entrySet()) {
    modify(entry.getValue());
}
```

A [`Map.Entry<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a representation of each of your map's key-value pairs, for convenient iteration.  If you want to do an operation on all of the keys, or all of the values of your map, then this would be the object you want to get from your map (as in, `a_enclavement.entrySet()`).